# How to create a "wall" with Drupal Commons?

Tags: blocks, 7

Does anyone know a way to show a sort of "wall" for any users, under the profile sections, like facebook with drupal commons? I think i'll have to add a block under the bio section right? My goal is that when a user will go to the profile of a trusted contact (friend) he/she can see all it's activities under the bio section.
However, if the user is not marked as trusted contact (friend) the activity will not be published.

I've found this answer but it's a little incomprehensible: https://forums.acquia.com/acquia-products-and-services/drupal-commons/drupal-commons-wall-facebook-wall ...

Comment: Have you looked at [Heartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat) or something similar? BTW, I find the post you are referring to a LOT incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm not sure that Heartbeat or Message are the best way... I think that drupal commons already has recorded the users activities and there is an easier way to view them

Comment: You are right, Commons Activity Streams.

Comment: Yes thanks, is this. I've added the "Commons Activity Streams (User-specific activity): Activity - Full view" (not sidebar view) but when i add the block it show a  "Placeholder for empty or inaccessible: Comm..." text

Comment: i've added  (User-specific activity): Activity - Full view, but seems not return results... maybe the view are not correctly configured? any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Flag

To implement "a trusted contact"? you could use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, whereas a user can "flag" another user as "***I trust that user***".

## Views

Create some view using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, in the format of a block, whereas you use the userid as a filter for such view. The actual content of such view should match with the "activities" you have in mind.

## Rules block visibility

Use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module to control the visibility of such block. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to creating a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Component to verify if the "current user" has flagged the user of the profile being viewed as a trusted contact. As per the great integration of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), that should really be like a "Getting started with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)" exercise.